# Global, modal reminder dialogs on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iOS app for medication reminders. Since it's important to take certain medications on time, I would like to show a modal global dialog on the user's phone. The alert would have two possible responses: "I have taken the medication" and "I have not yet taken the medication".

So far, I've tried doing this using local actionable notifications, but there are two major problems:

- When the app requests the ability to show actionable notifications and the user approves this, the settings are only set for "banner" level instead of "alert" level. The user has to manually change this setting.
- The response options are buried in the "Options" button of the alert.

Is there a saner way to create a global, modal, actionable alert on iOS? Surely apps like alarm clocks must implement something like this.

Code I use to register an actionable category - this asks the user to confirm that they want notifications, but then only sets the app to be able to create banners rather than alerts.

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *confirmAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
confirmAction.identifier = @"CONFIRM";
confirmAction.title = @"Yes";
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *snoozeAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
snoozeAction.identifier = @"SNOOZE";
snoozeAction.title = @"Snooze";
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *confirmSnoozeCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
confirmSnoozeCategory.identifier = @"CONFIRM_SNOOZE";
[confirmSnoozeCategory setActions:@[snoozeAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[confirmSnoozeCategory setActions:@[snoozeAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];
NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:confirmSnoozeCategory];
settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

Code I use to invoke the notification with said actionable category.

```
notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] initWithOptions:options]; // Options contains body, title, etc.
[notification setCategory:@"CONFIRM_SNOOZE"];
[notification setFireDate:[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30]];
[self.app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: Sir, you know, as your SO experience, that this kind of questions are total broad, is unclear what you asked, expecially without any code. I want to help you but without any reference it's impossible to do it..sorry.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano You are quite right, of course. I've added the relevant code bits.

Comment: Good , i will try to give an answer, great editing